# Integrating Hudson with MS Test?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, hudson, mstest

Is it possible to integrate [Hudson](http://hudson.dev.java.net/) with MS Test?

I am setting up a smaller CI server on my development machine with Hudson right now, just so that I can have some statistics (ie. [FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/) and compiler warnings). Of course, it would also be nice if it could just run my unit tests and present their output.

Up to now, I have added the following batch task to Hudson, which makes it run the tests properly.

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /runconfig:LocalTestRun.testrunconfig /testcontainer:Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll
```

However, as far as I know, Hudson does not support analysis of MS Test results, yet. Does anyone know whether the TRX files generated by `MSTest.exe` can be transformed to the [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) or [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) result format (because those are supported by Hudson), or whether there is any other way to integrate MS Test unit tests with Hudson?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hudson has a new plugin for MSTest.  Just specify the location of the .trx file and the work is done for you.  It wouldn't surprise me if the plugin used Allen's solution.

Comment: nice, I will have to check that out to see if it adds any functionality that my solution doesn't have.

Comment: Wow, how could I miss this being released? I guess I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: I think this plugin covers my needs pretty much for now. If someone needs something more sophisticated, thouh, give Allen's suggestion a try.

Comment: This plugin isn't much useful since we usually don't commit `trx` files. I thought the CI server was responsible for running the tests thus generating the trx itself

Comment: You don't need to commit the trx file.  Just configure the plugin to know where it will be once the tests are done.  You may get a warning when you first configure it if the trx doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You run a Windows batch job that calls mstest.exe to run your unit tests, specifying a .trx file. You point the plugin at the generated .trx file. @Trinition gave that as an answer.

Answer (score 17):

I've been meaning to write this as a guide and develop a plugin but I havent gotten around to it.  I know this question is old but I'm SURE someone else out there wants the same thing so here it is.

In the project configuration on Hudson:

**Execute Windows batch command**

```
SET MSTest="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"
SET XSLParser="C:\MsBuildNunit\msxsl.exe"

SET TestDLL=path-to-your-test-projects.dll
SET TestOutFILE=TestResults\some-unique-filename.trx
SET TransformedOutputFile=%TestOutFILE:.trx=%.xml
SET XSLFile=c:\MsBuildNunit\MSBuild-to-NUnit.xslt

MKDIR TestResults

%MSTest% "/testcontainer:%TestDLL%" /nologo /resultsfile:%TestOutFILE% 

%XSLParser% %TestOutFILE% %XSLFile% -o %TransformedOutputFile%

SET ERRORLEVEL=0
```

Then check the box "Publish NUnit test result report" and for "Test report XMLs" enter

```
TestResults/*.xml
```

There is an XSLT in C:\MsBuildNunit as well as msxsl.exe which comes from Microsoft.

You can download the MSBuild-to-NUnit.xslt from **[here](http://www.86th.org/MSBuild-to-NUnit.xslt)** and get msxsl.exe from microsoft  **[here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2FB55371-C94E-4373-B0E9-DB4816552E41&displaylang=en)** or you can just get the zipped copy of my MsBuildNunit folder that contains the xslt and exe **[here](http://www.86th.org/MsBuildNunit.zip)**

When run, it calls MSTest.exe which runs the tests and outputs the format in microsofts trx (xml) format.  Then it calls msxsl.exe with the xslt and the trx and translates it to nunits xml format.  At the end of the build, Hudson picks it up as any other Nunit test result and you are good to go.

Edited to add:
I forgot to mention, with this xslt we get full test results.  We have multiple test projects and multiple dll's and we get great feedback with the ability to trend graph, view the tests by name, view the statuses of the tests, and if it errors we get the error message along with the stack trace.  Basically almost everything that you would get with Nunit.

Edit (again): I just now added the test duration in the transform so it will show up in Hudson now!  Seems to work great for our tests.

Edit: I tried the new MSTest plugin and it currently does not support parsing multiple TRX files, just 1, so currently this is your only solution if you are like us and have multiple test assemblies that you have to run through MSTest.

Comment: This looks great, thanks! I may give it a try tomorrow, depending on what this new MSTest plugin has to offer.

Comment: I just found out that the MSTest plugin does not support parsing multiple trx files, so thats something this solution has over it.

Comment: The Jenkins MSTest plugin supports multiple TRX files, now: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8520

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537461/msbuild-to-nunit-transform-vs2010

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to use a variation of "hangy's" command line, and the MSTest plugin to successfully run and analyze/publish the test cases.  The biggest change I made was to specify the output file for mstest.exe and fore the MSTest plugin to consume that file (no wildcards allowed... must be actual filename).  For example, the following is my custom build step:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /runconfig:LocalTestRun.testrunconfig /testcontainer:MyProject1.Test/bin/Debug/MyProject1.Test.dll  /testcontainer: MyProject2.Test/bin/Debug/MyProject2.Test.dll /resultsfile:TestResults\HudsonJobTestResults.trx
```

exit 0

Notice that the "results file" is relative to the Job's workspace.  Thus, the MSTest plugin's result file to parse is:

```
TestResults\HudsonJobTestResults.trx
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Hudson has a [Plot Plugin](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin) which can be used to plot generic data. It's not the easiest plugin to configure and use if you have multiple data points per graph, but if you can parse your MS Test output and generate input files for the plugin, you can at the very least plot the trends of failed, successful, and total tests.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This sounds like a last resort - it could possible be easier to transform .TRX (XML) to JUnit/NUnit format using XSLT or so.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to use Hudson to perform analysis of MS Test results for historical purposes, but I've at least been able to figure out that if you use MSBuild and the Exec task, the Hudson build will properly be marked as "failed" if any of the tests fail.

```
<Exec Command=""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:"MyAssembly.dll"" />
```