# Is there a tool for creating historical report out of j/nunit results

Tags: testing, report

Looking for a way to get a visual report about:

1. overall test success percentage over time (information about if and how quickly tests are going greener)
2. visualised single test results over time (to easily notice test gone red that has been green for long time or vice versa to pay attention to a test that has just gone green)
3. any other visual statistics that would benefit testers and the project as a whole

Basically a tool that would generate results from the whole test results directory not just off the single (daily) run.

Generally it seems it could be done using XSLT, but it doesn't seem to have much flexibility to work with multiple files at the same time.

Does such a tool exist already?

Answer (score 1):

I feel fairly courageous to claim that most Continuous Integration Engines such as [Hudson (for Java)](http://hudson-ci.org/) provide such capability either natively or through plugins. In Hudson's case there's a few code coverage plugins available already and *I think* it does basic graphs from unit tests automatically by itself.

Oh and remember to configure the CI properly, for example our Hudson polls CVS every 10 minutes and if it sees any changes, it does all the associated tricks (get updated .java files, compile, run tests, verify dependencies etc.) to see if the build is still OK or not.

Comment: In 2023, Bitbucket (unfortunately, one of the top platforms) is still lacking most useful features of Junit reporting (historical comparison, attachments etc)

Answer (score 0):

[Hudson](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) will do this and it will work with Nunit ([here](http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/NUnit+Plugin)), Junit (natively), and MSTest.exe tests using the steps I outline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352703/integrating-hudson-with-ms-test/512092#512092).  It does all that you require and more.  Even if you want it to ONLY run tests and give you feedback on those, it can.

Answer (score 0):

There's such new report supporting NUnit \ JUnit called [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/). To retrieve information from NUnit you need to use [NUnit adapter](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-nunit), for JUnit - read the following [wiki page](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/JUnit). You can use it with Jenkins via respective [plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jenkins-plugin).