# Continuous Integration - with what to start: CruiseControl.NET vs TeamCity vs Visual Studio Team System

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, cruisecontrol.net

I'm new to Continuous Integration. I want an advice with what tool should I start deal with. I see that this is the biggest tools right now: CruiseControl.NET, TeamCity and Visual Studio Team System.

I'm using this tools: Visual Studio 2010, Mercurial, NAnt, NUnit.

Comment: Visual Studio Team System is another contender. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Team_System

Comment: I would actually choose [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) over CC.NET, as [many would](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582687/ci-hudson-with-net-vs-cruisecontrol-net)

Comment: VSTS isn't an option for him since hes using Mercurial, NAnt and NUnit.  TFS Build works out of TFS source control.

Comment: As I commented below - In less than an hour I had an automatic CI stack running against a codeplex mercurial repo with 1/2 hour checks, unit test coverage, tray notifier and visual studio integration, though the VS integration for mercurial is still vaporware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both TeamCity and CruiseControl.NET will work fine for this set of tools. Also you can consider alternatives :

- Hudson (Free, UI-based setup)
- Visual Studio Team System (expensive (about 6000$), UI-based setup)
- CruiseControl.NET (Free, Xml-based setup)
- TeamCity (Professional Edition of TeamCity is  free, UI-based setup)

The difference is :

1) Pricing. CruiseControl.NET and [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) are free and open source, while Visual Studio Team System and TeamCity cost money (However Professional Edition of TeamCity is also free).

2) Set up process. All systems have pretty simple UI to get up continuous integration processes except Cruise Control .NET - it uses XML-based configuration files instead ([Example](http://code.google.com/p/design-of-selenium-tests-for-asp-net/source/browse/trunk/_build/scripts/ccnet.config))

Essentially all you need from integration system is just to run nant script on commit event and show report. Every continuous integration system can do this. I would recommend Hudson because it is:

- Free
- Easy to set up

Comment: Whilst you mention that the Professional edition of TC is free, I feel you're misrepresenting it a tad.  You recommend Hudson because it is Free and Easy to Setup - both of which are equally true about TC.  You group TFS and TC in the same boat, when one costs significant money and the other can be free with few limitations, of which mostly affect large customers.

Personally, I would suggest that TC, Hudson and CC.NET are in the same pricing category, and TFS, FinalBuilder, Bamboo etc in the other.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend TeamCity - free for up to three agents, 20 projects and 20 users, runs a variety of builders (NAnt included) and can parse NUnit results (Hudson can do all this too I believe, however I have no used it, so I can't speak from experience).

Having worked with TFS, TeamCity, Bamboo and CC.NET, I can say that TC was the easiest to get up and running, the simplest to deploy multiple remote agents, get insight into builds, and integrated seamlessly with jabber, email, visual studio, windows task tray etc.  Just felt good.

Comment: I just setup teamcity for the first time to pull and build a mercurial repo on codeplex in about 15 minutes. Still working on the testing but I have a good feeling about this.

Comment: 10 more minutes RTFMing and I have a full CI stack running. Amazing. Painless. The last time I set up was CC.Net a few years ago. Painful.

Answer (score 4):

Teamcity unless you enjoy editing XML files.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration) on cc.net vs. teamcity for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Pulse http://zutubi.com/. Seems to be a bit pricey though. We use TeamCity and I really like it, my only complaint or observation is that it was built first and foremost for Java code builds. They have over time made it more generic, but a company that creates Java tools tends to lean one way and you get that kind of feeling with TeamCity to some extent, although like I said nowadays it's not so much true as a few years back. We use it from Java builds to SQL Server database builds and it works really nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're laze, you could always use easyCIS. It's cheap, easy to configure and you never have to learn what those build scripts are about. VS2010 is a planned feature though until it goes RTM.