# Xcode Continuous Integration and Mercurial

Tags: xcode, mercurial, continuous-integration

As I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH8-SW1)  OS X Server running on OS X Mavericks now supports continuous integration.

> The Xcode service supports two popular source control systems: **Git** and **Subversion**. You can use Git and Subversion repositories hosted on remote servers, and you can host and use Git repositories on the server running the Xcode service.

I was really confused that Apple ignores **Mercurial** in this case.

*So the questions:*

1. Are there any workarounds how to use Mercurial repository with XCode continious integration?
2. If NO, are there any else tools to provide continuous integration with Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I've also been trying to make the OS X Server Xcode service use Mercurial. I've tried using http://www.creaceed.com/mercurialplugin, but it looks like this doesn't affect the Xcode service's source control functionality. However, I believe that you could create a git repository that mirrors an hg repository using https://github.com/rfk/git-remote-hg.
2. As for other continuous integrations tools that do support Mercurial, we use TeamCity and it works well. See also: 
   [Recommendations for Continuous integration for Mercurial/Kiln + MSBuild + MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672509/recommendations-for-continuous-integration-for-mercurial-kiln-msbuild-mstest)

Comment: For those coming on this later you will find that the https://github.com/rfk/git-remote-hg readme has been updated to suggest that people use this project: https://github.com/felipec/git/wiki/git-remote-hg