# MSBuild to NUnit transform (VS2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I tried to use the xslt mentioned [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352703/integrating-hudson-with-ms-test) to turn MSTest trx into NUnit Xml (to get round a bug with MStest output in Bamboo) but seem to have no joy.

Is the trx format different for VS2010 ? (or is it just me?)

Answer (score 2):

The namespace has changed. Just replace

```
        xmlns:t="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006"
```

with

```
        xmlns:t="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010"
```

and it should work.